# If my company is going to be acquired for $50m, how can I avoid high taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax, start-up, merger-and-acquisition

Let’s say for example I have a company that is going to be acquired for $50m and I own half it as a cofounder.

How can I avoid a large tax hit?

I know someone who received $25m from an acquisition and walked away with $6m due to taxes and I want to avoid that nightmare.

All I know so far is that there is something to do with an S-Corp in a state with low/no capital gains tax…

Any other strategies to be aware of?

Comment: This feels more like a corporate accounting question and not personal finance. As such it is probably9 off topic for this site.

Comment: Qualified small business stock (QSBS, also known as section 1202 stock) is something that might apply to you if you meet several requirements.

Comment: At the time of the acquisition there's nothing much you can do. At best, if you can plan long enough ahead, you can switch residency to a low-tax jurisdiction (e.g.: move from California to Florida), but high-tax jurisdictions will try to challenge that.

Comment: I am doing math and with Federal and state income tax on $25M, taxes should not be more than $12M, so one should walk away with 13M. You should ask your friend about details for major items and should add to your question

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/q/qsbs-qualified-small-business-stock.asp

Answer (score 11):

When you're talking about this amount if money, you really shouldn't be asking volunteers on the Internet for advice. You can't afford *not* to hire professionals.

Comment: Yeah, “hire a lawyer and accountant” is the obvious answer.  (The follow-on is “why doesn’t he already have an accountant?”)

Comment: @RonJohn: I'm guessing the answer is "because this is a hypothetical rather than an actual case."

Comment: Personal Finance should also include questions that human keeps contemplating . If one knows any points regarding this question, it should be answered till that points with caveats

Comment: Questions whose answers will never be useful to readers are generally considered offtopic on Stack Exchange. And not all finance is personal finance,.